# How to use ReportViewerForMVC in ASP.NET CORE Web Application

Tags: asp.net-core, sqlreportingservice

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to integrate SSRS report into my asp.net core web app. I followed some tutorial on how to setup report viewer in asp.net mvc using the ReportViewerForMVC nuget package. However I encounter the following error. Hope someone can help to guide me on how to achieve this. Thanks alot!

Comment: add code in text format!!

Comment: Hi @GEE SOON, ReportViewerForMvc14 nuget does not support for asp.net core, it only supports asp.net.